# How should I take the struture 'that moment by'?

Tags: sentence-construction, clauses

In this following context, how should I understand this that clause ' that moment by'?

Should I take it as: 'that moment by moment'?

Context:

> All life and all existence here,
>
> With all its joy and all its pain,
>
> Depends all on a state of mind,
>
> And quick passes **that moment by**.

Source: P. 54
''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
(Four Lectures)
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Comment: It's not a clause.  The word "by" doesn't belong to "that moment", but to the verb: to **pass by**, which is a phrasal verb which means "to move past".  Also the word order has been changed, an example of anastrophe, often used in poetry.   In ordinary prose we could write:  "And that moment passes by quickly".

Comment: Thanks @Billy Kerr.

Comment: @SakyaKim: If you're reading this text because you're interested in the subject matter, that's all well and good. But you're not doing yourself any favours if you think it's gonna help you learn English.

Comment: Note that "moment by moment" implies some *rapidly changing* context. That's nothing to do with the cited text, which is pointing out that the entirety of a person's life (and indeed all the billions of years of life on Earth) are just a brief "blip" in the eternity of the universe.

Answer (score 3):

As the passage is set out as verse, it appears to be a 'poetic' way of saying "And that moment passes by quickly".

Comment: Thanks @Kate Bunting.